# Android text to speech cuts off another text to speech

Tags: android, eclipse

so I have a 3 `CountDownTimers`. 2 of the timers have the same time set. 1 has a different time set. After all timers reach 0, they restart again.

Well after about 3 restarts, the timers catch up with each other.. which is fine... however, I have it set so that at the 20 second mark, Timers 1 & 2 say something in text to speech. And Timer 3 also says something at the 20 second mark. The problem is that the whole phrase is not spoken because they are cutting each other off.

Currently, in all 3 of the countdowns i'm using:

```
tts.speak("20 seconds remaining.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

is this problem occuring because i'm using the same `TextToSpeech` (`tts`) ?
or maybe it has something to do with `QUEUE_FLUSH` and `null`?

And also if I change `QUEUE_FLUSH` to `QUEUE_ADD` the text just keeps repeating so that won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by using an `onUtteranceCompleted` callback that sets a boolean value to true when it's done speaking. This way, the voice doesn't get cut off.